# Nodelist content isn't logging

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

I have a website:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ik2xM.png
I'm trying refer to `.kuFilterBox` class name in Opera browser
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3OQj.png and get nothing https://i.stack.imgur.com/cN42w.png

If I'm trying refer to `.kuFilterBox` class name in Chrome browser - only in devconsole I got the result, but with `undefined`
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrMk0.png

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://js.klevu.com/core/v2/klevu.js"></script>

  <script src="https://js.klevu.com/theme/default/v2/category-page.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    klevu.interactive(function () {
      var options = {
        url: {
          protocol: 'https:',
          search: 'https://eucs3v2.ksearchnet.com/cs/v2/search' // your search URL
        },
        search: {
          apiKey: "klevu-14728819608184175" // your Klevu JS API Key
        },
        analytics: {
          apiKey: 'klevu-14728819608184175' // your Klevu JS API Key
        }
      };
      klevu(options);
    });
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var klevu_pageCategory = "Clothing";
    sessionStorage.setItem("klevu_pageCategory", klevu_pageCategory);
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="klevuLanding"></div>

</body>


<script src="./main.js"></script>

</html>
```

JS:

```
  const filterBox = document.querySelectorAll('.kuFilterBox');

  console.log(kuFilterBox);
```

Comment: If that JavaScript is in the `category-page.js` file, add the `defer` attribute to the `<script>` tag.

Comment: All `<script>` tags are placed before closing `</body>` tag. Place external tags first (`<scipt src='https://...js'></script>` ), then inline after (`<script>...</script>`). This ensures that the DOM has been rendered before the script executes.

Comment: I guess you are trying to fetch the item even before its populated, thats why you are getting empty but when you print it in dev console you get the value because by then its rendered in the dom. Put a debugger where you trying to fetch and see if the its present in dom at that time